# Using subscribe on event in FragmentDialog

Tags: android, otto

I using FragmentDialog for subscribe on events using otto library.

```
  @Subscribe
    public void onPickupRequestResponse (PassengerPickupRequestResponseEvent event){
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Event handled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dismiss();
    }
```

I register FragmentDialog in OnResume event and unregister in onPause methods.

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        App.bus.register(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        App.bus.unregister(this);         
    }
```

Then in activity I post event

```
 App.bus.post(new PassengerPickupRequestResponseEvent());
```

But my FragmentDialog does not handle this event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `onResume` and `onPause` you can override the `dismiss()` to unregister and in the `onCreateDialog` method you can register the Bus. 
Then you should be able to interact with the Bus.

Comment: I tried it but not happen. DialogFragment does not handle event.

Comment: do you get the event when you subscribe to it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, when i subscribe on event in active it's working;

Comment: my mistake. I have updated my answer. The `onCreateView` method is not called in Dialogs. The Dialog calls the `onCreateDialog` method, where you can register the bus.